Gaussian Process not fitting well // nearly constant predictions
I am a PhD student trying to optimize a chemical engineering process with Bayesian Optimization. I have 5 variables and 3 objectives/responses I want to optimize, so I chose Botorch with the qneHVi acquisition function. Based on 9 experiments in a Latin Hypercube design I wanted to build 3 Gaussian Process models (one for each objective with each the same 5 experiment setup variables), however looking at the model fit with a leave-one-out CV the predictions are not really well. In fact, the predictions seem to be quite constant close to 0, regardless of the actual value:



Using the acquisition function, still, apparently meaningful experiments are suggested, so I dont really what is the problem here.
I used my own gpytorch implementation of a GP with a 5/2 matern kernel and not the botorch singletaskgp implementation as i wanted to adjust the kernel at a later stage. However, replicating with botorch led to a similar result.
here is my code and data:
    Var 1   Var 2   Var 3   Var 4   Var 5   Obj 1   Obj 2   Obj 3
Exp1    3.345911123 1.282585746 24.78727644 10.33125039 5.129742851 66.89109782 211.0078103 0.003871563
Exp2    0.94396231  1.770899113 3.067068382 8.039039653 2.652766884 10.15453364 265.4918227 0.054579702
Exp3    15.5953593  0.023661887 23.03150739 8.4371572   4.26648812  14.98230932 50.86460311 0.007612711
Exp4    16.94915825 2.179165462 34.14320571 10.61673422 0.330075681 29.84653487 66.49137341 0.036539522
Exp5    20.31415073 0.679037133 10.6830292  9.726434813 1.766469252 6.424410122 48.22291768 0.012609046
Exp6    10.47798514 0.9477502   39.33536393 8.732075456 1.041022082 -1.12386E-29    -4.49545E-29    0.001
Exp7    11.5984412  2.315368022 8.091917151 9.48091678  3.882355098 54.98412965 544.8796154 0.020630854
Exp8    6.981697681 0.414511413 30.07606994 10.70026137 2.671012046 78.40264141 198.2829009 0.009186194
Exp9    22.68822129 1.52641427  14.90080246 9.055420487 5.793706981 34.42754513 180.6572556 0.001832616

model_class = gpytorch_singletask_class_const.GPModel

(model_class:
class GPModel(gpytorch.models.ExactGP, botorch.models.gpytorch.GPyTorchModel):

    def __init__(self, train_x, train_y, likelihood):
        super().__init__(train_x, train_y, likelihood)
        self.mean_module = gpytorch.means.ConstantMean()
        self.covar_module = gpytorch.kernels.ScaleKernel(
            gpytorch.kernels.MaternKernel(nu=2.5, ard_num_dims=train_x.shape[1]) # Dynamic ARD configuration
        )


    def forward(self, x):
        mean_x = self.mean_module(x)
        covar_x = self.covar_module(x)
        return gpytorch.distributions.MultivariateNormal(mean_x, covar_x)
)

bounds = torch.tensor([
    [0.0, 25.0],  
    [0.0, 2.5], 
    [2.0, 40.0], 
    [8.0, 11.0],  
    [0.0, 6.0]  
], dtype=torch.float64)


X = df[parameter_names].to_numpy()
y = df[objective_names].to_numpy()

# Initialize data by normalization, standardization
train_x_normalized, train_y_standardized, scalers = preprocessing.prepare_data(X, y, bounds)

(prepare_data: 
def prepare_data(X, y, bounds):
    # Convert numpy arrays to torch tensors
    train_x = torch.tensor(X, dtype=torch.float64)
    train_y = torch.tensor(y, dtype=torch.float64)

    # Normalize inputs based on the bounds 
    train_x_normalized = normalize(train_x, bounds)

    # Initialize scalers for each objective
    num_objectives = train_y.shape[1]
    scalers = [StandardScaler() for _ in range(num_objectives)]

    # Create an empty list to store standardized outputs
    standardized_outputs = []

    # Standardize each objective independently
    for i in range(num_objectives):
        obj_scaled = scalers[i].fit_transform(train_y[:, i].unsqueeze(1).numpy())
        standardized_outputs.append(torch.tensor(obj_scaled, dtype=torch.float64))

    # Combine the standardized outputs back into a single tensor
    train_y_standardized = torch.cat(standardized_outputs, dim=1)

    return train_x_normalized, train_y_standardized, scalers)


# Training, validating, and saving the models

# Var1
model1, likelihood1, losses1 = gpytorch_singletask_fitting.fit_gp_model(
    train_x_normalized,
    train_y_standardized[:, 0],
    model_class,
    noise= 0.05,
    num_train_iters=1000,
    save_model=True,
    filepath=path + "model1.pth"
)

(fit_gp_model:
def fit_gp_model(train_x, train_y, model_class, noise=0.01, num_train_iters=1000, lr=0.01, save_model=False,
                 filepath=None):
    """
    Fits a Gaussian Process model to the training data and optionally saves the final model, including the optimizer
    state, to a specified path.

    Parameters:
    - train_x (Tensor): Input features.
    - train_y (Tensor): Target outputs.
    - model_class (class): GP model class to be instantiated.
    - noise (float): Initial noise level for the likelihood.
    - num_train_iters (int): Number of training iterations.
    - lr (float): Learning rate for the optimizer.
    - save_model (bool): Whether to save the model and optimizer after training completes.
    - filepath (str): The file path where the model should be saved if save_model is True.

    Returns:
    - model (GPModel): Trained GP model.
    - likelihood (GaussianLikelihood): Trained likelihood.
    - losses (list): List of losses during training.
    """
    likelihood = gpytorch.likelihoods.GaussianLikelihood()
    likelihood.noise = noise

    model = model_class(train_x, train_y, likelihood)
    model.train()
    likelihood.train()

    optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=lr)
    #_________________________________________
    # scheduler = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.StepLR(optimizer, step_size=100, gamma=0.1)
    #_________________________________
    mll = gpytorch.mlls.ExactMarginalLogLikelihood(likelihood, model)

    losses = []
    for i in range(num_train_iters):
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        output = model(train_x)
        loss = -mll(output, train_y)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        #_________________________________
        # scheduler.step()
        #_________________________________
        losses.append(loss.item())

    model.eval()
    likelihood.eval()

    if save_model and filepath:
        save_gp_model(model, filepath)

    return model, likelihood, losses)

gpytorch_singletask_fitting.plot_training_loss(
    losses1,
    path=path + "model1"
)

validation_scores_1 = gpytorch_singletask_validation.loocv_gp_model(
    train_x_normalized,
    train_y_standardized,
    0,
    model_class=model_class,
    path=path + "model1",
    make_plot=True
)

(loocv_gp_model:
def loocv_gp_model(train_x, train_y, y_column, path, model_class, make_plot=True):
    data_range = train_y[:, y_column].max() - train_y[:, y_column].min()  # Range of the data

    validation_scores = []
    actuals = []
    predictions = []

    for i in range(len(train_x)):
        # print(f"Processing fold {i + 1}/{len(train_x)}...")

        # Use all but one data point for training
        train_indices = list(range(len(train_x)))
        train_indices.pop(i)
        test_index = [i]

        train_subset_x = train_x[train_indices]
        train_subset_y = train_y[train_indices]
        test_x = train_x[test_index]
        test_y = train_y[test_index, y_column]

        # Fit the model

        model, likelihood, losses = fit_gp_model(train_subset_x,
                                                 train_subset_y[:, y_column],
                                                 model_class,
                                                 num_train_iters=1000)
        model.eval()
        likelihood.eval()

        # Evaluate the model on the left-out data point
        with torch.no_grad(), gpytorch.settings.fast_pred_var():
            observed_pred = likelihood(model(test_x))
            pred_mean = observed_pred.mean
            mse = (pred_mean - test_y).pow(2).mean()
            nrmse = torch.sqrt(mse) / data_range  # Calculate NRMSE

        validation_scores.append(nrmse.item())
        predictions.append(pred_mean.item())
        actuals.append(test_y.item())

    # print(f"Fold {i + 1} completed.")

    print("All folds processed.")
    average_nrmse = sum(validation_scores) / len(validation_scores)
    print(f"Average NRMSE: {average_nrmse}")

    # Generate plots
    if make_plot:
        plt.figure(figsize=(7.5, 2.5))
        plt.plot(range(1, len(train_x) + 1), validation_scores, marker='o')
        plt.xlabel('Experiment')
        plt.ylabel('NRMSE')
        plt.title(f'LOOCV Average NRMSE: {average_nrmse}')
        plt.tight_layout()
        plt.savefig(f"{path}_nrmse.png", dpi=300)
        plt.close()

        plt.figure(figsize=(7.5, 7.5))
        plt.scatter(actuals, predictions, alpha=0.7)
        for j, text in enumerate(range(1, len(actuals) + 1)):
            plt.annotate(text, (actuals[j], predictions[j]))
        plt.plot([min(actuals), max(actuals)], [min(actuals), max(actuals)], 'r')  # line y=x
        plt.xlabel('Actual')
        plt.ylabel('Predicted')
        plt.title('Actual vs Predicted')
        plt.tight_layout()
        plt.savefig(f"{path}_pred_vs_actual.png", dpi=300)
        plt.close()

    return validation_scores  # , actuals, predictions)
# Var2
model2, likelihood2, losses2 = gpytorch_singletask_fitting.fit_gp_model(
    train_x_normalized,
    train_y_standardized[:, 1],
    model_class,
    noise=0.05,
    num_train_iters=1000,
    save_model=True,
    filepath=path + "model2.pth")

gpytorch_singletask_fitting.plot_training_loss(
    losses2,
    path=path + "model2"
)
validation_scores_2 = gpytorch_singletask_validation.loocv_gp_model(
    train_x_normalized,
    train_y_standardized,
    1,
    path=path + "model2",
    model_class=model_class,
    make_plot=True
)

# Var3
model3, likelihood3, losses3 = gpytorch_singletask_fitting.fit_gp_model(
    train_x_normalized,
    train_y_standardized[:, 2],
    model_class,
    noise=0.05,
    num_train_iters=1000,
    save_model=True,
    filepath=path + "model3.pth"
)

gpytorch_singletask_fitting.plot_training_loss(
    losses3,
    path=path + "model3"
)

validation_scores_3 = gpytorch_singletask_validation.loocv_gp_model(
    train_x_normalized,
    train_y_standardized,
    2,
    model_class=model_class,
    path=path + "model3",
    make_plot=True
)

I hope that was everything that was needed to recover what I did. I hope this was comprehensible. I am deeply thankful for every help I could get here and pleast do not hesitate to write in case something is missing or you have an idea. thank you so much!!

Have you considered other types of regression? It seems like linear regression creates a reasonable fit.
$obj1 = -4.41188 + 27.0437 var1 - 3.01808 var1^2 + 0.0830304 var1^3 - 
 5.75319 var2 - 6.28793 var2^2 + 6.49103 var2^3 + 0.792111 var3 + 
 0.0735169 var3^2 - 0.00264704 var3^3 + 0.792111 var4 + 
 0.0735169 var4^2 - 0.00264704 var4^3 - 1.61708 var5 - 
 3.76787 var5^2 + 0.548096 var5^3$

$obj2 = -11.5629 + 103.039 var1 - 11.2016 var1^2 + 0.307054 var1^3 - 
 20.0969 var2 - 17.6958 var2^2 + 34.531 var2^3 - 0.346857 var3 - 
 0.115311 var3^2 + 0.00140867 var3^3 - 0.346857 var4 - 
 0.115311 var4^2 + 0.00140867 var4^3 + 10.804 var5 + 17.5499 var5^2 - 
 3.16706 var5^3$

$obj3 = 0.00378471 - 0.0153041 var1 + 0.000986034 var1^2 - 
 0.0000125743 var1^3 + 0.00385157 var2 + 0.00569098 var2^2 + 
 0.000278908 var2^3 - 0.00173766 var3 + 0.000102851 var3^2 - 
 1.15632*10^-6 var3^3 - 0.00173766 var4 + 0.000102851 var4^2 - 
 1.15632*10^-6 var4^3 + 0.00512559 var5 + 0.0100376 var5^2 - 
 0.00199734 var5^3$

It looks like you can get a bit better fit than linear regression if using symbolic regression. There are several different SR implementations in Python (GPLearn, StackGP, etc.).
$obj1 = 26.7191 \left(2.50821\, +\sin \left(\text{var1}^{1/\text{var5}}\right)+\text{var4}+\frac{1}{\text{var4}}\right)-301.071$

$obj2 = 31.295 (\text{var4}-1.46066 \text{var5} (\cos (\text{var5})-1. \text{var2}))-299.571$

$obj3 = 0.000537876\, -\frac{0.145293}{\text{var3} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\frac{\text{var2}}{\text{var3}}-1. \text{var5}}{\text{var2}}\right)}$

It seems like you may be interested in using the models for experimental design, assuming you are doing an uncertainty-based sampling you could use symbolic regression and generate a model ensemble to query for uncertainty. In which case, I got the following fits (bands represent uncertainty).



This doesn't fix the problem you are encountering with gaussian process approaches, but these could provide alternative strategies to solve the problem.

Hi Nate,
thank you very much for your response! That looks indeed very interesting. I myself tried a PLS model and a RandomForest with not very much success tbh, I am surprised about the MLR tbh. Great idea with the symbolic regression, too! That helps indeed.
Unfortunately, I more or less rely on the gaussian process models here in this task, as a further step in the project is to modify the kernel with physics. Do you think it would be possible for you to try the GPs yourself, too?
i would be very thankful as I am a bit desperate here.
BTW: are your plots also performed with a loocv?
